# IPA install size decreases, but download size increases?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipa

Recently I'm trying to decrease my App's size of downloading.
The main bottleneck is that there is a .sqlite file built in my app's bundle, it costs about 21 mb.

While I successfully decreased the .sqlite file size from **21mb -> 17mb**.

The **install size** report from iTunes connect did also decreased from **99.3mb -> 95.9 mb**, but the **download size increased** about 200kb, as image shown below

[image]

And this is file size report after decreased .sqlite size

[image]

I have totally no idea of how this would happen, decreased Install size, but increased download size. I can swear that the only thing I've changed is the .sqlite file

Does anyone have a clue?
Thank you!

Environment:

- Xcode 10.2.1
- iOS 12 Base SDK
- Pure Objective-C
- Bitcode enabled
- Optimization level: Fastest, Smallest

Comment: Download the file or do an ad hoc build, and open the app bundle. You can see for yourself what occupies the space.

Comment: @matt Yup I'm pretty sure the .sqlite file is occupying the space. The problem is I've already decreased the file size of sqlite, how come the download size will increase, but install size decreased?

Comment: There is no need to be “pretty sure”. You can see for yourself. — Also if you really think 21 MB is a problem for a 99 mb app, you can use on demand resources to reduce the initial download size.

Comment: @matt I'm saying pretty sure is because of before I try to decrease my .sqlite file size, I do inspect the app bundle by unzipping the .ipa, and the largest file in my app bundle is the .sqlite file, that's why I try to decrease the sqlite file size. I'll consider using on demand resources, but I'm still curious about how my issue would happen, thank you for answering! :)

Comment: Well, what do you care? The app is packed in some unknown way for downloading. You don’t know the algorithm and there’s nothing you can do about it. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232424/my-app-is-showing-install-size-instead-of-download-size-in-app-store. As I said, if the goal is to come in well under the 100mb cut off, you can use ODR.